# how to simulate a file under linux?

Tags: linux, openssh, openssl, stdin

I'm basically trying to do this using `openssh`:

I have a private key, however it isn't in file (it's in memory). Now, I want to create the public key in `openssh` format. For that I would generally run `ssh-keygen -y -f <filename>`.
However I do not have a file name, since i don't have a file. I'd like to feed `openssh` from the standard input somehow instead. How would I do that?

If it isn't possible I wouldn't mind having `openssh` generate both private and public keys BUT I can't write them to a file. Instead I would like to write them both to stdout. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain your aversion to files? What exactly are you trying to do here? Why can't you use files?

Comment: I am doing this as an automated task from a java server. I could write a file to the filesystem, run ssh-keygen on it and then delete it. However, this is an unnecessary overhead. I would like to just give the private key from stdin and redirect the output to stdout. the ssh-keygen utility does not seem to allow me to do this although to me this seems very basic

Comment: Perhaps [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706177/how-to-generate-ssh-compatible-id-rsa-pub-from-java/10343300#10343300) might help?